# In purana, any incident boy marrying girl older than him?

Tags: puranas, marriage

Is there any story in Hinduism were girl is older than boy? 
Now a days, we see many people marrying older women ( many celebrities) this is accepted according to Hinduism?

Comment: Whenever heavenly girls like Urvashi marry earthly kings, the age of the girl is greater than the boy.

Comment: Whom she married?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Hinduism SE! Unfortunately this question is a duplicate. In future, please try the search bar to verify whether or not your question has been answered. It can be a bit difficult to find due to the nature of this stack exchange, so please don't be discouraged when a question is closed as a duplicate.